# How to implement queue management system in Redis

Tags: algorithm, sorting, redis, queue, priority-queue

Im trying to implement queuing system using redis. So lets say we have this list:

```
> LPUSH listTickets 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

and as mobile app user someone was assigned number 4, and another user number 6. Now I want to display to them how many tickets are in front of them ( also to calculate the waiting estimated time). Now this may seem easy,

```
> LPOP listTicket
"4"
```

then we broadcast the result (the current ticket number to be called), then on mobile app everyone will subtract it from their own ticket number. for example my current ticket is `6` so `6-4=2` That way every user know how many tickets are ahead

However once you want to add feature to let the user delete their ticket or pushing it to the end of the queue, things get complicated. After deleting for example

```
> LRANGE listTicket 0 -1 
1) "2"
2) "4"
3) "6"
4) "7"
5) "8"
```

when we `LPOP listTicket` we will get number 2 and the mobile app with ticket 6 will calculate 6-2 and get 4 which is the wrong calculation.

Do you have any algorithm in mind? Is getting the index of every ticket in the list every time someone delete their ticket an expensive process to calculate? Should I just send all tickets in the queue and let the users calculate their own position?

---

I want the system to be scale-able. So can the redis-node server handle total of 50 thousands (over different queues or lists) connected mobile apps getting their ranking in the queue they subscribed their ticket to.

I thought about using `ZRANK` but how will this load the server?

Comment: Redis documentation contains complexity for every operation. For example for LRANGE time complexity is O(S+N) where S is the distance of start offset from HEAD for small lists, from nearest end (HEAD or TAIL) for large lists; and N is the number of elements in the specified range. See https://redis.io/commands/lrange

Comment: Just a question, why would you want to do that? There are already priority queue libraries that work well with Redis such as Celery (python), Resque (ruby) or Bull (NodeJS TypeScript), bee-queue (NodeJS javascript).